# laravel 5 ajax, keep get 500 internal erro with csrf token

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I want to make a search program to get data from huge data table. User can search data from to column, code/kode and name (every data have 1 code/kode). If a user click search button, using AJAX, send request to server, then the client get result and display it at the table.

Here the my view :

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-inline form-inline" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
         {!! Form::select('jenis-select',['Kode BU','Nama BU'],null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
         {!! Form::text('value-select','',['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
         <button type="button" id="cari-bu" class="btn btn-default">Cari</button>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Kode BU</th>
                <th>Nama BU</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="hasil-cari"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The result of search will display on `<tbody>` with attribut `id="hasil-cari"`
this is my ajax :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content')}
    });
    $('#cari-bu').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'select_bu',
            type: 'post',
            data: {'_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                'jenis': $('select[name=jenis-select]').val(),
                'value': $('input[name=value-select]').val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#hasil-cari').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And this is the controller that handle AJAX:

```
public function postSelect() {
        if (Request::ajax()) {
            $input = Input::all();
            if ($input['jenis'] == 0) {
                $hasil = Daftarbu::where('kodebu', $input['value'])->get();
            } elseif ($input['jenis'] == 1) {
                $hasil = Daftarbu::where('namabu','LIKE','%'.$input['value'].'%')->get();
            }
            $hasilAkh = '<tr>';
            foreach ($hasil as $dHasil){
                $hasilAkh .= '<td>'.$dHasil->kodebu.'</td><td>'.$dHasil->namabu.'</td>';
            }
            $hasilAkh .= '</tr>';
            return $hasilAkh;
        }
    }
```

My route:

```
Route::post('select_bu','Pelayanan@postSelect');
```

I have put this `meta` at `<head>` tag

```
<meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}"/>
```

With that code I keep get 500 internal error. Can anyone find the problem ?

Comment: Put the token as input hidden field

Comment: Put this with your form {{csrf_field}}

Comment: In your ajax, your URL is defined as `url: 'select_bu'`. Are you using named routes? If this Javascript is echoed out un the page, you might want to use something like `url: '{!! route('url_to _submit to') !!}',`. More info on named routes: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes

Comment: @JustinOriginBroadband still the same using named route

Comment: Did you try putting {{csrf_field}} inside the form and remove the meta csrf_token? What's the result?

Comment: Also, remove $.ajaxSetup()

Comment: @user2407971 still got 500 internal server error

Comment: Dump out your `routes.php`, it may be that you have somehow managed to avoid loading the `web` middleware that includes csrf checking. Also, run and dump out for us your generated  routes `php artisan route:list` and show those results as well. Lastly, can you double check your HTML form is actually well-formed (no pun intended). You might not have any opening `form` tag

Comment: Which version of laravel is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `routes.php`

```
    Route::post('/select_bu',['as'=>'select_bu','uses'=>'Pelayanan@postSelect']);
```

In your Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')}
        });

        $('#cari-bu').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{!! route('select_bu') !!}',
                type: 'post',
                data: 'jenis': $('select[name="jenis-select"]').val(),
                      'value': $('input[name="value-select"]').val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#hasil-cari').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

The `$.ajaxSetup({})` you have loads the token into your ajax setup. There's no need to include it as part of your `<form>` or as a param for sending as part of your ajax object key-pairs to send on the request. Most likely the error occurred due to the two `_token` values conflicting with each other once they reached the `VerifyCsrfToken` Middleware, seeing as the `_token` referenced by  `$('input[name=_token]')` doesn't seem to get matched?

On that note, the selectors should be written:

```
    $('input[name="_token"]')
```

I have corrected this in the code I've supplied.

For more information:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: i repair my code like what you suggest to me, but unfortunately, i still got 500 internal error

Comment: solved it works, i found the problem. the problem on my controller on using elloquent model. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dump out your `routes.php`, it may be that you have somehow managed to avoid loading the `web` middleware that includes CSRF checking.

In 5.2 only the maintenance middleware is executed on every request. Everything else like cookies, sessions, and CSRF has been moved into the web middleware group.

You may need something like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    // ...
});
```

Also, run and dump out for us your generated  routes `php artisan route:list` and show those results as well.

Lastly, can you double check your HTML form is actually well-formed (no pun intended). You might not have any opening `form` tag e.g.:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'foo/bar', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
    {{-- Form::select --}}
{!! Form::close() }}
```

[Relevant documentation](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#opening-a-form) for `Form`, if not mistaken.